# hide certain hidden folders from my sublime project

Tags: sublimetext2

How do I hide certain hidden folders that are nested 3 folders deep from my sublime project.

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/C/Users/me/Desktop/files/siteFiles/happy site/trunk"
        },
        {   
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["myHiddenFolder",".svn", "._d", ".metadata", ".settings"]
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you mean _all_ folders three levels deeper than trunk, or just _certain_ subfolders?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your `.sublime-project` file like so:

```json
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "path": "/C/Users/me/Desktop/files/siteFiles/happy site/trunk",
            "folder_exclude_patterns": ["myHiddenFolder",".svn", "._d", ".metadata", ".settings"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Save the file, and you should be all set. For more info on project settings, check out [the docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html).

Comment: `folder_exclude_patterns` doesn't go under `settings`; his syntax is correct. He's asking for additional patterns to hide folders of depth three or more.

Comment: @ProtractorNinja why wouldn't it work to any depth? At any rate, thanks for pointing out the syntax error, I've fixed it. Both items should go in the same array, not one after another. I think that `folder_exclude_patterns` could still go in a separate `settings` section, as it's valid there as well as in the `folders` section.

Comment: A pattern applies to any level of depth, but I couldn't figure out if he meant "all folders deeper than level 3", "these specific folders" (that aren't working with my _current_ file), or something else entirely. After re-reading, I _think_ he meant the latter, so your reworded answer should work. Maybe explain why his original wasn't working, though?